# What reward(s) can I get from fishing?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

What reward can I get from fishing at the Fishing Hole?  Is there treasure or equipment to be won from fishing, even if I catch the Hylian Loach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can earn a heart piece if you catch a fish as a kid, and the golden scale (which allows deeper, longer diving) as an adult.

As per Krazer, in the comments, there is a [50 Rupee reward](http://zeldawiki.org/Hylian_Loach) from catching the Loach, and the owner will refuse to keep it in the fish tank (where your record catch is usually displayed).

Comment: No reward for the loach... *expect* for [a purple rupee](http://zeldawiki.org/Hylian_Loach) (worth 50 rupees). Talk to the pond owner after you catch one and select the second option "I want to talk about something..."

Comment: @Krazer Whoa. I had no idea fishing in Ocarina of Time was so well documented...